# SSL not working on eth0

Tags: ssh, certificates

All secure connections like https, ssh are not working when I connect through eth0. However they work perfectly fine when connected through wireless.

Is this some issue with certificates in the system? or is it got to do with the network? How to fix this issue?
Will deleting all certificates help, if so where to find and delete those certificates?

Please suggest.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

By "dont't work" I mean all the connections requiring SSL don't work, like ssh, https. When I do ssh I get an error "Connection refused by remote computer".
Other normal connections work however.
Regarding firewall, there is no rule, I just see all as accept.

The wireless connection, which goes through same gateway works fine though.

Comment: What does it mean they don't work? Do you any error message? Please give more details.

Comment: Do other connections work over eth0?

Comment: Are you sure HTTPS is does neither work? Try https://twitter.com/. Could it be your network admin blocking secure connections on certain LAN IPs?

Answer (score 1):

From a networking side it could be related to the default gateway being bound to the wireless interface.

We would need to see the output for the following to confirm:

```
ifconfig
```

and

```
route -n
```

The other possible reason is from an application layer.  These services may not be configured to listen on an IP associated with that interface.  The following command will show you what is listening and on what IP.

```
netstat -an | less
```

Answer (score 0):

Who's/What network is eth0 connected to? It could be that someone in control of one of the routers/machines your eth0 traffic goes through could be refusing to carry traffic that uses an encrypted protocol. If they are doing that, it is quite likely that they are hoping you will switch to an insecure protocol so they can listen in, possibly to get passwords or spy on you or block certain things.

My advice: if Firefox/Chromium complains about certificate errors, do not accept any new certificates! It could be whoever is messing with your eth0 connection trying to trick you into a man-in-the-middle attack. (That means that you are tricked into having an encrypted connection to the attacker, who connects to the end website and forwards your requests. Of course, he can read the connection when he does this.)
If the network is one you pay for access to, have technical support help you if possible. If the network is one you pay for access to and the person you're paying is doing this, threaten to buy service from someone else unless they stop it.